# Swift how to make a For-Statement thread-safe?

Tags: swift, for-loop

I have a SwiftyJson For-Loop like

```swift
self.jsonObj = JSON(value)

for i in 0 ..< self.jsonObj["customer"].count {

    if self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_A"].string == "Mr Abcde" 
            || self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_A"].string == "Mr Bcde" 
            || self.jsonObj["custome"][i]["Group_B"].string == "Mr Abcde" 
            || self.jsonObj["customer"][i]["Group_B"].string == "Mr Bcde" 
    {
        self.jsonObj["customer"].arrayObject?.removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}
```

The problem now is that going to the loop with more than 360 Datasets all elements were found but not removed from the array, because the For-Loop is not thread-safe.

How can I make a thread-safe For-Loop?

Comment: Are you sure it's a threading problem? Without much investigation, it looks like you're removing index 0, in which case index 1 now becomes index 0. Try doing the loop backwards instead of forwards.

Comment: You probably mean thread safe, but threat safe is a brilliant description of the issue ;-)